# Scala: Performing operation while iterating over the items in foreach loop

Tags: scala, foreach

I am very beginner in scala and I am trying to do some operation, using foreach loop , but while doing that I am getting an error as "value foreach is not a member of Int"

Can you please help me out with the problem .. Below is the code , also I am not looking to solve this using tail recursion.

```
  def findTheFactorial(n : Int): Int = {
    var finalNo = 1
    for(no <- n)
      finalNo = finalNo * no

    return finalNo
  }
```

Comment: n is just an integer . loops are done on collections

Comment: Go it thanks Ramesh !

Comment: `(2 to n).product`

Answer (score 1):

foreach loop works on collections, and `n` is not a collection. For example, you can do the below:

`for(no <- List(1, 2, 3)) {
   println(no)
}`

Scala doesn't have a for loop with 3 parts(initialization, condition & incrementing).

What you want to do is iterate n times. In order to do that, you can create a `Range` which is a collection like below:

`1 to n`

The above generates a Range between 1 and `n` and when you iterate over that range, then you get the desired result. So your code should go something like below:

`def findTheFactorial(n : Int): Int = {
  var finalNo = 1
  for(no <- (1 to n))
    finalNo = finalNo * no
  return finalNo
}`